# Silverlight Download a Project File

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a series of Files (word, pdf, ect) that are stored in my application and the idea is to allow the end user to download these files at their choosing. How is this done in silverlight? I tried using a SaveFileDialog but I must not be doing it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Add your code in your question, also please specify error if any.

Comment: When you say files are stored in your app, do you mean they're a document on a web site/remote location or do you mean they're embedded in the application itself?

Comment: They are actually embedded in the application itself. What I am trying to do is just allow the user to save them to their local machine.